# Magento 2 get categories by store Query

Tags: magento2, database

I want to get all enable categories for specific store from query in Magento 2 database. As I tried from database query from table `catalog_category_entity_int`

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id`=46 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY `entity_id`
```

Where **46** is attribute id for enable attribute.

With this query i am getting all categories ids but for all stores categories are same if i change **store_id** the results are same for all stores

Comment: Your question needs to be updated as `catalog_category_entity_int` does not contain any column named `entity_id` which you are using in GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the value of the attribute `is_active` which correctly you found the id `46` can be in one or more rows for the same category.

Lets take an example:

Lets assume the Category with the `entity_id = 2`.

In the table `catalog_category_entity_int` for sure there will be one row for the `default store_id`  which is the `0` , if you went to the admin area and changed `is_active` attribute for another `store view` or `website`  lets say for the `french`  store view which's id is `1` (this ids are for the table `store`) then in the table `catalog_category_entity_int` you will have another row with another value for this attribute. So now you will have 1 row for the default store_id and one for the french store_id.

When your user will be in french store view he will get the value with the `store_id=1` if the user will be in any other store view or website the default store_id will be used.

[image]

To get the categories for the specific store view for many categories there wont be a value in other store_id except 0 .

So I would suggest to export values for each store view and then combine them to see which one you need.

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id`=46 AND `store_id`=1 

SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id`=46 AND `store_id`=0
```